# java printing : incorrect paper size

Tags: java, printing, awt

im trying to print a pdf in A4 size but the output varies from the expected one.

this is what it looks like

[image]

but it supposed to be like this

[image]

both images are same resolution

this is the code that generates this output.

```
PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
pj.setPrintService(service);
PageFormat pf = new PageFormat();
Paper paper = new Paper();
paper.setSize(595, 842); // a4 in px
paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, 595, 842);
pf.setPaper(paper);

Book book = new Book();
book.append(pages, pf, pdfFile.getNumPages());
pj.setPageable(book);

pj.print();
```

basically its just shrunk. what should i do to fix this?

and by the way, im not using a real printer. im using a [virtual printer](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lucid/cups-pdf/) that takes a print request and outputs a pdf.

Comment: Do you have the code that generates the table, cause i don't see anything wrong with this part of the code.

Comment: my application can both print and save the pdf. the correct image(2nd image) was generated by saving the image(A4 size of course). and the incorrect one(1st image) is the same but PRINTED. so i think there is nothing wrong with the table drawing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have found a solution to this. i used javax.print library instead of java.awt.print.

```
File file = new File("path/to/pdf");
DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PDF;
PrintRequestAttributeSet attr = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
attr.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fis, flavor, null);
DocPrintJob job = printService.createPrintJob();
job.print(doc, attr);
fis.close();
```

now it gets printed correctly.